# added instance variable not shown with inspect in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Inspect will tell object representation. so I tried this:

```
animal = "cat"
animal.instance_variable_set(:@a, "dog")
p "inspect object animal: #{animal.inspect}"
```

But inspect only gave me "cat", I cannot see @a="dog"

If I do this:

```
puts "instance variables are: #{animal.instance_variables}"
```

Then I can see [:@a] as output

Why is inspect not giving me everything?

Thanks

Comment: Because [`Object#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Object.html#method-i-inspect) has been overridden by [`String#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/String.html#method-i-inspect)( says - **Returns a printable version of str, surrounded by quote marks, with special characters escaped.**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String` overrides `#inspect` ([`String#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-inspect)) to return the original string wrapped in quotes, as opposed to [`Object#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-inspect), which dumps everything.

You shouldn't need to re-define `String#inspect` to account for your special use-case though. If you want your string to have some additional data, you should create your own class instead:

```
class Animal
  def initialize(name, other)
    @name = name
    @other = other
  end
end

Animal.new("cat", "dog")
# #<Animal:0x007faf9404d828 @name="cat", @other="dog">
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why is inspect not giving me everything?

DON'T DO THIS -> remove the `String#inspect` method and see what happen.

```
class String
  remove_method :inspect
end

animal = "cat"
animal.instance_variable_set(:@a, "dog")
animal # => #<String:0x9976b94 @a=#<String:0x9976b80>>
```

The above output is what [`Object#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Object.html#method-i-inspect) explained -

> The default inspect shows the object’s class name, an encoding of the object id, and a list of the instance variables and their values (by calling inspect on each of them).

But, in your case you are calling, [`String#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-inspect) which is the overridden version of `Object#inspect`.

> Returns a printable version of str, surrounded by quote marks, with special characters escaped.

And your output is what exactly documentation mentioned.

I wanted to give you some *in sight*. Now don't play like this with Ruby core classes, create your own custom classes, and play with them as much as you can.